# How to call function from external js file onload or onclick event into my html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an function with json data inside an variable. Inside that function I use those data to display them on a div. But when I place that code inside html document using  my code  it works without onload event or another but what I want is for example to put these code in an external .js file and put them together as a function and to call it whenever I want from the html document using onclick event for example.

This is my code but when I write at onclick="takvimi()" it does nothing. That external js file its called in the  part so I don't know why its not working.

```
function takvimi(){
    var data= {
        "Shkup":[
          {
            "Dita": "1",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "2",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "3",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "4",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "5",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "6",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "7",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "8",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "9",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "10",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "11",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "12",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "13",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "14",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "15",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "16",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "17",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "18",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "19",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "20",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "21",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "22",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "23",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "24",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "25",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "26",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "27",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "28",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "29",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
          {
            "Dita": "30",
            "Data":"17-kor-15",
            "Imsaku": "05.50",
            "Iftari": "18.31"
          },
        ]}
          <!-- Takvimi per Shkup  -->
        var outputSK ='<ul style="padding:0px 15px;color:#fff ;text-shadow: none;font-family: Dosis;font-size:medium; font-weight: normal;" >';
        for (var i in data.Shkup)
        {
            outputSK+='<li>Dita: ' + data.Shkup[i].Dita + ' Ramazan <span style="float:right">Data: '+ data.Shkup[i].Data + '</span><br>';
            outputSK+='Imsaku: ' + data.Shkup[i].Imsaku + '<span style="float:right">Iftari: '+ data.Shkup[i].Iftari + '</span></li>';
        } 
        outputSK+= '</ul>';
        document.getElementById("takvimi-Shkup").innerHTML = outputSK;

}
```

The reason is because the json data are much more than this ones and I want to get cleaner and smaller html document size.

UPDATE: My html code is here http://pastebin.com/tkdhhg8g

page with id #takvim is where I want to display the data..

js/mysript.js is the while which contains the function takvimi()

Comment: Where is your script-tag located, in the <head>-tag or in the end of the <body>-tag? And can you post the script-tag?

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Comment: Can you confirm the file has been loaded successfully? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: How do you know it does nothing? Did you use a debugger? The resulting HTML has css `color: #fff` (white), so it isn't visible here: http://jsfiddle.net/47txk8a2/

Comment: I updated the main post with the html code link but at the console there isn't any problem. THe color is #fff because the background is purple.

@P5Coder I tried in the manner you sent me without onload or anything only the div with that name but doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Actually it works `color: #fff;` `which is white` whats why you are not able to see any thing
**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5n2amepv/)**

Comment: I updated the main post with the code there are no error at the console

Comment: @  albpower there should not be remove `color: #fff;` from `var outputSK ='<ul style="padding:0px 15px;color:#fff ;text-shadow: none;font-family: Dosis;font-size:medium; font-weight: normal;" >';` and you will see all :P

Comment: Look in the generated code, jsfiddle automatically adds an window.onload event to your code appearantly. That's why it works on JSFiddle.

Comment: @ozil the div is empty its not the color problem..  http://i.imgur.com/ohWyw1G.png

Comment: @ albpower I have tested it is working, have you included the `takvimi` `reference` in you file containing `onclick="takvimi()"`

Answer (score 0):

Place your script-tag (`<script src="js/myscript.js"></script>`) just before the closing of the body (`</body>`). It should work.

So your code will be:

```
<head>
   <!-- JS LIDHJET  -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body style="font-family:Roboto" onload="tranzicionet();">

 <!-- Kanali 1 - homepage -->
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="b" style="background: radial-gradient(circle, #9a4d61, #4b3a48);" >

<!-- MENU Panel -->
  <div id="Menu1" data-role="panel" data-display="push"  style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9a4d61, #4b3a48); border-right:solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/pendimi.png" style="border:none;width: 100%;display: block;margin: 0px auto;"> 
    </div>  
    <div><span class="titulli">Menu</span></div>
    <div class="menu" id="menu">
        <a href="#home"  data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-microphone "></i>  Kanali 1</span></a>
        <a href="#kanali-2" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-microphone"></i>  Kanali 2</span></a>
        <a href="#fb-wall" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o "></i>  Lajme</span></a>
        <a href="#takvim" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar "></i>  Takvimi</span></a>
        <a href="#transmetime" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-youtube-play "></i>  Transmetime</span></a>
        <a href="#info" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-info "></i>  Info</span></a>
    </div>
    <div><span class="titulli">Kontakt</span></div>
    <div class="Live" id="Live">
        <a href="skype:radiopendimi?call" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-skype "></i>  Thirr në Skype</span></a>
        <a href="tel:0041445869903" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-phone "></i>  Thirr në telefon</span></a>
        <a href="#dergomesazh" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>  Dërgo Mesazh</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="copyright">&copy; 2015 - Radio Pendimi<br/>Dizajnuar nga Afrim Azizi</div>
    </div> <!-- END MENU PANEL -->


<!-- content -->
<div data-role="none">
<!-- Header -->
    <div class="header">
        <div class="menuPanel">
            <a href="#Menu1" style="text-decoration:none"><span class="butonat"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i> MENU</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            <span>Kanali 1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <span class="butonat" onclick="window.location.reload();"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-lg"></i> </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="background: url('images/equalizer.png'); background-size:100%">
        <img id="cc_strinfo_trackimageurl_kanali1" class="cc_streaminfo logo pulse" style="width: 50%; background: #fff; margin: 20px auto; padding: 5px; display:block; min-height:170px; min-width:170px;"/>
    </div>

    <!-- AUDIO PLAYER -->
    <div id="status-titulli"> 
        <span style="background:#6d4253; padding:8px; border-radius:8px"><i class="fa fa-signal fa-lg"></i>  Jeni duke dëgjuar:  <i class="fa fa-signal fa-lg fa-flip-horizontal"></i></span> 
        <br><br>
            <span id="cc_strinfo_song_kanali1" class="cc_streaminfo"></span><br>
            <!-- <div id="cc_recenttracks_kanali1" class="cc_recenttracks_list">Loading ...</div><br> -->
    </div>
    <div id="player" >
        <audio src="http://217.172.180.29:8000/;$type=mp3" id="player-1" preload="metadata"></audio>
        <div style="margin:15px auto 35px"> <!-- Player controls start -->
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('player-1').play()" class="btn_controli"> <i class="fa fa-play fa-3x"></i></span>
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('player-1').pause()" class="btn_controli"> <i class="fa fa-stop fa-3x"></i></span>
        </div> <!-- Player controls end -->
    </div>
    <!-- Nderrimi i kanaleve -->
    <div style="text-align:center; margin: 25px auto">
        <a href="#home" style="text-decoration:none"><span class="butonat"><i class="fa fa-microphone fa-lg"></i> Kanali 1</span></a>
        <a href="#kanali-2" style="text-decoration:none"><span class="butonat"><i class="fa fa-microphone fa-lg"></i> Kanali 2</span></a>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
<!-- End Page -->




<!-- Kanali 2 -->
<div data-role="page" id="kanali-2" data-theme="b" style="background: radial-gradient(circle, #9a4d61, #4b3a48);" >

<!-- MENU Panel -->
  <div id="Menu2" data-role="panel" data-display="push"  style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9a4d61, #4b3a48); border-right:solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/pendimi.png" style="border:none;width: 100%;display: block;margin: 0px auto;"> 
    </div>  
    <div><span class="titulli">Menu</span></div>
    <div class="menu" id="menu">
        <a href="#home"  data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-microphone "></i>  Kanali 1</span></a>
        <a href="#kanali-2" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-microphone"></i>  Kanali 2</span></a>
        <a href="#fb-wall" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o "></i>  Lajme</span></a>
        <a href="#takvim" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar "></i>  Takvimi</span></a>
        <a href="#transmetime" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-youtube-play "></i>  Transmetime</span></a>
        <a href="#info" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-info "></i>  Info</span></a>
    </div>
    <div><span class="titulli">Kontakt</span></div>
    <div class="Live" id="Live">
        <a href="skype:radiopendimi?call" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-skype "></i>  Thirr në Skype</span></a>
        <a href="tel:0041445869903" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-phone "></i>  Thirr në telefon</span></a>
        <a href="#dergomesazh" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>  Dërgo Mesazh</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="copyright">&copy; 2015 - Radio Pendimi<br/>Dizajnuar nga Afrim Azizi</div>
    </div> <!-- END MENU PANEL -->

<!-- content -->
<div data-role="none">
<!-- Header -->
    <div class="header">
        <div class="menuPanel">
            <a href="#Menu2" style="text-decoration:none"><span class="butonat"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i> MENU</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            <span>Kanali 2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <span class="butonat" onclick="window.location.reload();"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-lg"></i> </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="background: url('images/equalizer.png'); background-size:100%">
        <img id="cc_strinfo_trackimageurl_kanali2" class="cc_streaminfo logo pulse" style="width: 50%; background: #fff; margin: 20px auto; padding: 5px; min-height:170px; min-width:170px; display:block;"/>
    </div>

    <!-- AUDIO PLAYER -->
    <div id="status-titulli"> 
        <span style="background:#6d4253; padding:8px; border-radius:8px"><i class="fa fa-signal fa-lg"></i>  Jeni duke dëgjuar:  <i class="fa fa-signal fa-lg fa-flip-horizontal"></i></span> 
        <br><br>
            <span id="cc_strinfo_song_kanali2" class="cc_streaminfo"></span><br>
            <!-- <div id="cc_recenttracks_kanali1" class="cc_recenttracks_list">Loading ...</div><br> -->
    </div>
    <div id="player" >
        <audio src="http://217.172.180.29:8002/;$type=mp3" id="player-2" preload="metadata"></audio>
        <div style="margin:15px auto 35px"> <!-- Player controls start -->
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('player-2').play()" class="btn_controli"> <i class="fa fa-play fa-3x"></i></span>
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('player-2').pause()" class="btn_controli"> <i class="fa fa-stop fa-3x"></i></span>
        </div> <!-- Player controls end -->
    </div>
     <!-- Nderrimi i kanaleve -->
    <div style="text-align:center; margin: 25px auto">
        <a href="#home" style="text-decoration:none"><span class="butonat"><i class="fa fa-microphone fa-lg"></i> Kanali 1</span></a>
        <a href="#kanali-2" style="text-decoration:none"><span class="butonat"><i class="fa fa-microphone fa-lg"></i> Kanali 2</span></a>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
<!-- End Page -->    



<!-- Informacione -->
<div data-role="page" id="info" style="background: radial-gradient(circle, #9a4d61, #4b3a48);">
<!-- MENU Panel -->
  <div id="Menu3" data-role="panel" data-display="push"  style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9a4d61, #4b3a48); border-right:solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/pendimi.png" style="border:none;width: 100%;display: block;margin: 0px auto;"> 
    </div>  
    <div><span class="titulli">Menu</span></div>
    <div class="menu" id="menu">
        <a href="#home"  data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-microphone "></i>  Kanali 1</span></a>
        <a href="#kanali-2" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-microphone"></i>  Kanali 2</span></a>
        <a href="#fb-wall" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o "></i>  Lajme</span></a>
        <a href="#takvim" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar "></i>  Takvimi</span></a>
        <a href="#transmetime" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-youtube-play "></i>  Transmetime</span></a>
        <a href="#info" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-info "></i>  Info</span></a>
    </div>
    <div><span class="titulli">Kontakt</span></div>
    <div class="Live" id="Live">
        <a href="skype:radiopendimi?call" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-skype "></i>  Thirr në Skype</span></a>
        <a href="tel:0041445869903" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-phone "></i>  Thirr në telefon</span></a>
        <a href="#dergomesazh" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>  Dërgo Mesazh</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="copyright">&copy; 2015 - Radio Pendimi<br/>Dizajnuar nga Afrim Azizi</div>
    </div> <!-- END MENU PANEL -->

<div data-role="none">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="menuPanel">
            <a href="#Menu3" style="text-decoration:none"><span class="butonat"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i> MENU</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            <span>Info</span>
        </div>
    </div>
 <img src="images/pendimi.png"  class="logo pulse"/>
    <p align="center">
      <a href="mailto:info@radio-pendimi.com" style="text-decoration:none; text-shadow:none; color: #fff;font-weight: 500;font-size: 20px; font-family: Dosis;">info@radio-pendimi.com </a><br>
      <a href="http://radio-pendimi.com" style="text-decoration: none; text-shadow:none; color: #fff; font-weight: 500; font-size: 20px; font-family: Dosis;">http://radio-pendimi.com </a><br>
        <span style="text-decoration: none; text-shadow:none; color: #fff; font-weight: 500; font-size: 15px; font-family: Dosis;">Programuar & Dizajnuar nga Afrim Azizi</span> <br>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/radioopendimi" target="_blank"><img src="images/find-us-on-facebook.png" style="width: 170px; padding: 5px;"/></a>
  </p>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- End Page -->


<!-- Takvim -->
<div data-role="page" id="takvim" style="background: radial-gradient(circle, #9a4d61, #4b3a48);" >
<!-- MENU Panel -->
  <div id="Menu4" data-role="panel" data-display="push"  style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9a4d61, #4b3a48); border-right:solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/pendimi.png" style="border:none;width: 100%;display: block;margin: 0px auto;"> 
    </div>  
    <div><span class="titulli">Menu</span></div>
    <div class="menu" id="menu">
        <a href="#home"  data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-microphone "></i>  Kanali 1</span></a>
        <a href="#kanali-2" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-microphone"></i>  Kanali 2</span></a>
        <a href="#fb-wall" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o "></i>  Lajme</span></a>
        <a href="#takvim" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar "></i>  Takvimi</span></a>
        <a href="#transmetime" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-youtube-play "></i>  Transmetime</span></a>
        <a href="#info" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-info "></i>  Info</span></a>
    </div>
    <div><span class="titulli">Kontakt</span></div>
    <div class="Live" id="Live">
        <a href="skype:radiopendimi?call" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-skype "></i>  Thirr në Skype</span></a>
        <a href="tel:0041445869903" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-phone "></i>  Thirr në telefon</span></a>
        <a href="#dergomesazh" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>  Dërgo Mesazh</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="copyright">&copy; 2015 - Radio Pendimi<br/>Dizajnuar nga Afrim Azizi</div>
    </div> <!-- END MENU PANEL -->

<div data-role="none">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="menuPanel">
            <a href="#Menu4" style="text-decoration:none"><span class="butonat"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i> MENU</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            <span>Takvim</span>
        </div>
     </div><br><br><br>
    <div style="text-align:center; color:#fff; text-shadow:none; margin:20px 10px; font-family:Dosis; font-size:medium">
          Ramazani është muaji i nëntë i kalendarit Islam. Muaji zgjatë 29 ose 30 ditë bazuar në vëzhgimet pamore të hënës së re dhe sipas llogarive të shumëta të hartuara në hadithe. Fjala ramazan vjen          nga arabishtja Ramaḍān (رمضان‎) që do të thotë vapë ose thatësirë. Ai është muaji i agjërimit, që do të thotë shmangia e ushqimit dhe lëngjeve, mardhënieve seksuale, fjalëve dhe sjelljeve të             këqija dhe gjërave të tjera të ndaluara në Islam. Agjërimi është një nga pesë shtyllat e Islamit dhe zgjatë nga agimi deri në perëndimin e diellit.Në fund të ramazanit vjen fitër bajrami, apo             festa e prishjes së agjërimit. Nga lidhjet e mëposhtme mund të gjeni kohën e Imsakut (agimit) dhe kohën e Iftarit (perëndimit) për tre kryeqendrat shqiptare Tiranë,Prishtinë dhe Shkup. Ju dëshirojmë agjërim të lehtë dhe të pranuar tek Allahu xh.sh. 
    </div>
    <div id="takvimat">
        <div><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none"><span class="btn-takvimat"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg"></i> Tiranë</span></a></div>
        <div><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none"><span class="btn-takvimat"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg"></i> Prishtinë</span></a></div>
        <div><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none"><span class="btn-takvimat"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg"></i> Shkup</span></a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="takvimi-Shkup"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Page -->


<!-- Transmetime -->
<div data-role="page" id="transmetime" style="background: radial-gradient(circle, #9a4d61, #4b3a48);">
<!-- MENU Panel -->
  <div id="Menu7" data-role="panel" data-display="push"  style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9a4d61, #4b3a48); border-right:solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/pendimi.png" style="border:none;width: 100%;display: block;margin: 0px auto;"> 
    </div>  
    <div><span class="titulli">Menu</span></div>
    <div class="menu" id="menu">
        <a href="#home"  data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-microphone "></i>  Kanali 1</span></a>
        <a href="#kanali-2" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-microphone"></i>  Kanali 2</span></a>
        <a href="#fb-wall" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o "></i>  Lajme</span></a>
        <a href="#takvim" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar "></i>  Takvimi</span></a>
        <a href="#transmetime" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-youtube-play "></i>  Transmetime</span></a>
        <a href="#info" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-info "></i>  Info</span></a>
    </div>
    <div><span class="titulli">Kontakt</span></div>
    <div class="Live" id="Live">
        <a href="skype:radiopendimi?call" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-skype "></i>  Thirr në Skype</span></a>
        <a href="tel:0041445869903" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-phone "></i>  Thirr në telefon</span></a>
        <a href="#dergomesazh" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>  Dërgo Mesazh</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="copyright">&copy; 2015 - Radio Pendimi<br/>Dizajnuar nga Afrim Azizi</div>
    </div> <!-- END MENU PANEL -->

<div data-role="none">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="menuPanel">
            <a href="#Menu7" style="text-decoration:none"><span class="butonat"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i> MENU</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            <span>Transmetime direkte</span>
        </div>
     </div><br><br><br>
    <div style="text-align:center; color:#fff; text-shadow:none; margin:20px 10px; font-family:Dosis; font-size:medium">
          Këtu mund të ndiqni transmetimet direkte të tribunave dhe organizimeve të ndryshme që transmetohen direkt në Radio Pendimi përmes kanalit zyrtar në Youtube. 
    </div>
    <div id="transmetime-list" class="embed-container"></div>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- End Page -->    



<!-- Dergo Mesazh -->
<div data-role="page" id="dergomesazh" style="background: radial-gradient(circle, #9a4d61, #4b3a48);">

    <!-- MENU Panel -->
  <div id="Menu5" data-role="panel" data-display="push"  style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9a4d61, #4b3a48); border-right:solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/pendimi.png" style="border:none;width: 100%;display: block;margin: 0px auto;"> 
    </div>  
    <div><span class="titulli">Menu</span></div>
    <div class="menu" id="menu">
        <a href="#home"  data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-microphone "></i>  Kanali 1</span></a>
        <a href="#kanali-2" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-microphone"></i>  Kanali 2</span></a>
        <a href="#fb-wall" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o "></i>  Lajme</span></a>
        <a href="#takvim" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar "></i>  Takvimi</span></a>
        <a href="#transmetime" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-youtube-play "></i>  Transmetime</span></a>
        <a href="#info" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-info "></i>  Info</span></a>
    </div>
    <div><span class="titulli">Kontakt</span></div>
    <div class="Live" id="Live">
        <a href="skype:radiopendimi?call" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-skype "></i>  Thirr në Skype</span></a>
        <a href="tel:0041445869903" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-phone "></i>  Thirr në telefon</span></a>
        <a href="#dergomesazh" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>  Dërgo Mesazh</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="copyright">&copy; 2015 - Radio Pendimi<br/>Dizajnuar nga Afrim Azizi</div>
    </div> <!-- END MENU PANEL -->

<!-- content -->
<div data-role="none">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="menuPanel">
            <a href="#Menu5" style="text-decoration:none"><span class="butonat"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i> MENU</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            <span>Dërgo Mesazh</span>
        </div>
     </div><br><br>
    <form class="form" id="callAjaxForm">
    <p class="name">
        <input name="emri" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Emri" id="name" data-role="none"  />
      </p>

      <p class="text">
        <textarea name="comment" class="validate[required,length[6,30]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Mesazhi" data-role="none" ></textarea>
      </p>


      <div class="submit" style="margin: 0px 12px;">
        <button id="submit" type="submit" >DËRGO</button>
        <button id="reset" type="reset" >PASTRO FUSHAT</button>
      </div>
       <h3 id="notification" align="center" style="font-color:green;"></h3>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- footer -->

</div>
<!-- End Page -->




<!-- Facebook wall -->
<div data-role="page" id="fb-wall" style="background: radial-gradient(circle, #9a4d61, #4b3a48);" >
 <!-- MENU Panel -->
  <div id="Menu6" data-role="panel" data-display="push"  style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9a4d61, #4b3a48); border-right:solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/pendimi.png" style="border:none;width: 100%;display: block;margin: 0px auto;"> 
    </div>  
    <div><span class="titulli">Menu</span></div>
    <div class="menu" id="menu">
        <a href="#home"  data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-microphone "></i>  Kanali 1</span></a>
        <a href="#kanali-2" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-microphone"></i>  Kanali 2</span></a>
        <a href="#fb-wall" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o "></i>  Lajme</span></a>
        <a href="#takvim" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar "></i>  Takvimi</span></a>
        <a href="#transmetime" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-youtube-play "></i>  Transmetime</span></a>
        <a href="#info" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-info "></i>  Info</span></a>
    </div>
    <div><span class="titulli">Kontakt</span></div>
    <div class="Live" id="Live">
        <a href="skype:radiopendimi?call" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-skype "></i>  Thirr në Skype</span></a>
        <a href="tel:0041445869903" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-phone "></i>  Thirr në telefon</span></a>
        <a href="#dergomesazh" data-role="none"><span><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>  Dërgo Mesazh</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="copyright">&copy; 2015 - Radio Pendimi<br/>Dizajnuar nga Afrim Azizi</div>
    </div> <!-- END MENU PANEL -->   

<!-- content -->
<div data-role="none">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="menuPanel">
            <a href="#Menu6" style="text-decoration:none"><span class="butonat"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i> MENU</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            <span>Lajme & Njoftime</span>
        </div>
     </div><br><br><br>
<div id="ibacor_fb_content">
<!-- Your facebook streaming -->
<div class="ibacor_fb_streaming"></div>
</div>
</div><!-- content -->

</div>
<!-- End Page -->


<script src="js/myscript.js"></script>   <!-- here is located that takvimi function -->
    <!-- Skripta -->
    <script src="js/jquery.ibacor-fb-streaming.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://217.172.180.29:2199/system/streaminfo.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://217.172.180.29:2199/system/recenttracks.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=PLBm6IaQX_2oLhbcD8AvsKyZdfD2lSvpqb&key=AIzaSyDhDZjburmzpaoH39Uj4dnU6X_GRLbCVW0&callback=broadcast"></script>
```

Comment: I don't see an onclick event for the takvimi() function in your code? Maybe it's that

Comment: here is how I call the function <span class="btn-takvimat" onlclick="takvimi();"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg"></i> Shkup</span>

Comment: i hade an syntax error in onclick now its working .. However onload doesn't works. I placed it at this page div onload tag (pages id #takvim)

Comment: You should place it in the pages body tag, like in the code above.